# Fill out a PDF Form with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, pdf, web-applications

I have a react application that needs to be able to take some string values such as a name, email, etc. The values need to be then filled out in a pdf template and flattened to a final pdf file that can be downloaded / exported within the react application.

**Pseudo-code of a possible solution:**

String variables collected from website (name, email, etc)

Function called that grabs our PDF template

Then by id within the pdf template, each field is filled out

The final pdf version with filled out fields is then flattened

Final PDF can be downloaded / exported on users end

Comment: Can you add some code that shows what you've attempted or at least some pseudo-code that shows the method that you think it would work.

Comment: @theastronomist yes, I have added some

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code of a possible answer: (you need to run a manual test cycle first)

---

String variables collected from website data

String Function called that fills your FDF text template

Then by double click of the FDF text copy of  template, each field is auto loaded to fill the PDF blank.

The final PDF version with filled out fields is then flattened and saved in the server PDF viewer.

Final PDF can be served for download then viewed by users application/PDF.

***To convert to a repeating program you can use an FDF loader in a loop to replace the double click step.***